# Why does "client.get_all_emojis" return an empty list?

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm started using discord.py, now I'm trying to add reactions to messages. Unfortunately if I run my code this is the output I get:

Code:

```
....
print('List emojis:')
print(list(client.get_all_emojis()))
print('Done')
....
```

Output:

```
List emojis:
[]
Done
```

What am I doing wrong? What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Client.get_all_emojis`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.get_all_emojis) only returns the custom emojis it can see, which are represented as [`Emoji`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Emoji) objects.  Regular emojis are represented with their unicode representations as string objects.

Try adding a custom emoji to your server and running your command again.

You can use the names of unicode characters to send the corresponding basic emoji:

```
await client.add_reaction(message, "\N{thumbs up sign}")
```

Comment: Oh, I see. Just to make sure I get it right: if I want to use "basic" emojis, I need to use their unicode? E.g. for the thumbsup emoji: `await client.add_reaction(message, "\U0001F44D")`? If yes, then could you edit your answer to make it "complete"? (...should have written that my goal is that...)